# R function call without loading package

Tags: r, package, function-calls, bioconductor

I want to use functions from the Bioconductor packages `hypergraph` and `hyperdraw` without loading the packages. When running an example from the `hyperdraw` vignette

```
dh1 <- hypergraph::DirectedHyperedge("A", "B", "R1")
dh2 <- hypergraph::DirectedHyperedge(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"), "R2")
hg <- hypergraph::Hypergraph(LETTERS[1:5], list(dh1, dh2))
hgbph <- hyperdraw::graphBPH(hg)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in hyperdraw::graphBPH(hg) : could not find function "hyperedges"
```

If I try to load `hyperedges`:

```
hyperedges <- hyperdraw:::hyperedges
```

I get the error

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'hyperedges' not found
```

When I load both packages using `library` or `require`, I get no error (in running the above code without `hypergraph::` and `hyperdraw::`).

The reason why I do not want to load the packages is because I am building a package which uses `hyperdraw` and `hypergraph` in only one function and I'd rather put these packages into `Suggests` than into `Depends` in my `DESCRPTION` file.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: HAven't tried to run this but try: `hyperedges <- hyperdraw:::hyperedges`

Comment: That gives an error as well, see edited post

Comment: If you build a package that uses functions from `hyperdraw` and `hypergraph` in even a single function, you **must** put them in your `DESCRIPTION` file at least as `Imports:` (which is preferred to `Depends:` in any case).  As far as I know there is no way around this. `Suggests:` is for packages used only in vignettes and examples.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I see, I jus re-read the section in 'Writing R extensions'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hyperdraw has this in it's DESCRIPTION file

```
Depends:      R (>= 2.9.0), methods, grid, graph, hypergraph, Rgraphviz
```

and it's relying on finding `hypergraph::hyperedges` on the `search()` path. Personally, I think hyperdraw should include a line

```
importFrom(hypergraph, hyperedges)
```

in it's NAMESPACE file. Currently, the best thing to do is to add Depends: hyperdraw to your DESCRIPTION file, and to `importFrom(hyperdraw, <whatever functions you need>)`. I have contacted the maintainer of hyperdraw to ask them to update the NAMESPACE as above; you could then merely `Imports: hyperdraw`. I think you're just making work for yourself and frustrating your users by trying to use Suggests or other approaches to subvert the need for formal dependencies.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it correctly, `hyperedges` is not exported by `hyperdraw`? I got it to run now with `hyperdraw` in Depends and `hypergraph` in Imports and I load all the functions I need in my `NAMESPACE`. I guess I'll keep it that way for now. Many thanks!